# pandas dataframe rebuild based on cells

Tags: pandas, dataframe

after a lot of testing I have ended with this df:

```
    Date           1     2    3  4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   2019-01-02  59.92   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN 197.28  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN 96.59   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN 275.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN 209.94  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 99.83   NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 257.89  NaN NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 215.54  NaN NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 187.06  NaN
0   2019-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 386.9
```

Would be nice any kind of trik to put all this values on the same row. Any idea?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via  `groupby()` and `sum()`:

```
df=df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

output:

```
  Date     1      2     3     4      5     6      7      8      9     10
2019-01-02 59.92 197.28 96.59 275.0 209.94 99.83 257.89 215.54 187.06 386.9
```

Comment: @AgustinGonzalezRibas updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @HenryEcker not sure which one op wants so posted both **:)**

Comment: No, sorry the point is make only one row with all values

Comment: As you can see all rows have same date, i want one row with that date and all avlues in that row

Comment: @AgustinGonzalezRibas updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 2):

An option with [`groupby first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) in case this would need to be performed for multiple different types where `sum` may not behave as expected:

```
df = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).first()
```

```
      Date     1      2     3     4      5     6      7      8      9    10
2019-01-02 59.92 197.28 96.59 275.0 209.94 99.83 257.89 215.54 187.06 386.9
```